# McNemar 2X2 test: What is the meaning of "Number of missclassified examples by neither "

Tags: statistics

## Introduction

I am using the *McNemar* test explained in section **3.1** of the following [article](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/dietterich98approximate.pdf)  in order to assess the performance of 2 algorithms alg1 and algo2 . My question concerns the meaning of the elements in 2x2 table.

---

The algorithms are  applied on the **same** dataset composed of 9000 queries. I want to classify the queries. As an evaluation criterion we use the **accuracy**. If is defined as follows:

- `If` a query was classified correctly. Then increment the accuracy by 1
- `Else` do nothing

  Accuracy = (Number of correctly classified queries)/(Total number of queries)

---

## 2x2 table

I will post in the section the definitions provided in the article. I provide my own understading of it. My problem is with definition 2. Please let me know if it's correct:

1. **Number of queries missclassified by both alg1 and algo2** (n00): Number of the incorrectly classified queries
2. **Number of queries missclassified by neither alg1 and algo2** (n11): Number of correctly classified queries in both **alg1** and **algo2**
3. **Number of queries missclassified by alg1 and not algo2** (n01): Number of incorrectly classified queries in only **alg1**
4. **Number of queries missclassified by alg2 and not algo1** (n10): Number of incorrectly classified queries in only **alg2**

   |n00 | n01|

   |n10 | n11|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number of missclassified examples by neither`

means queries where both algorithms classified the query correctly.

Example of binary classification

```
SAMPLE ID | EXPECTED CLASSIFICATION | ALGO1 CLASS | ALGO2 CLASS
1           GROUP A                   GROUP A       GROUP B
2           GROUP A                   GROUP A       GROUP A
3           GROUP B                   GROUP A       GROUP A
4           GROUP B                   GROUP A       GROUP B
```

- ID1 would add to n10
- ID2 would add to n11
- ID3 would add to n00
- ID4 would add to n01

Comment: oh thank you I was really confused on what it meant. Because I am just using the accuracy as an evaluation measure.